# USB touchscreen on Android 4.0.3 -> not possible to select (only moving the pointer)

Tags: usb, touchscreen, hid, lcd

Good morning guys.

I bought a LCD embedded display with a resistive touch screen integrated. 
The TS is interfaceable via USB.

I have connected it to a device running Android 4.0.3 and the touch is correctly recognized as externale HID.
PROBLEM: the tapping (pressing) is not recognized as selection/confirmation...the only thing that happens, when I tap the screen, is to move the pointer(arrow) in corrispondance of the coordinated of my finger..like I moved a mouse HID without left left clicking

It's not possible for me to scroll or to select something --> big mess for me :(

Please keep in mind that I have another LCD with integrated USB TS that works proprerly. I can select icons in case I tap on them and I can scroll the windows etc -> exactely like a mouse with left button always clicked -> OK for me!!!

Maybe it is a matter of drivers but I have no specific ideas.

P.s. I have no specific drivers for the device.

Any suggestion guys? Please help me :)

Thank you in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

You need to create **.idc** configuration file for your device.

Process described here http://source.android.com/tech/input/input-device-configuration-files.html

For example if you have device with name XYZ Touchscreen, create file **XYZ_Touchscreen.idc** in **/system/usr/idc/**
with content like this:

```
# Basic Parameters
touch.deviceType = touchScreen
touch.orientationAware = 1
touch.gestureMode = default
device.external = 1
touch.usingJitterFilter = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

android by built in support for any HID-MOUSE or HID-DIGITIZER.
it also need a helper file based on any one of following format.
if no such helper files are found then touchscreens will act as tochpad.

You can use linux evtest tool to check the type of usb device !

Reference:

### https://source.android.com/devices/input/input-device-configuration-files.html

Input device configuration files are located by USB vendor, product (and optionally version) id or by input device name.

### The following paths are consulted in order.

```
/system/usr/idc/Vendor_XXXX_Product_XXXX_Version_XXXX.idc
/system/usr/idc/Vendor_XXXX_Product_XXXX.idc
/system/usr/idc/DEVICE_NAME.idc
/data/system/devices/idc/Vendor_XXXX_Product_XXXX_Version_XXXX.idc
/data/system/devices/idc/Vendor_XXXX_Product_XXXX.idc
/data/system/devices/idc/DEVICE_NAME.idc
```

---

Example for Microchip AR1100 USB device as HID-DIGITIZER 
/system/usr/idc/Vendor_04d8_Product_0c03.idc

```
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

#
# Emulator keyboard configuration file #1.
#

# Basic Parameters
touch.deviceType = touchScreen
touch.orientationAware = 1

# Size
touch.size.calibration = diameter
touch.size.scale = 0
touch.size.bias = 0
touch.size.isSummed = 0

# Pressure
# Driver reports signal strength as pressure.
#
# A normal thumb touch typically registers about 200 signal strength
# units although we don't expect these values to be accurate.
touch.pressure.calibration = amplitude
touch.pressure.scale = 0.005

# Orientation
touch.orientation.calibration = none
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I myself have been searching on this for months now. It seems most of the touchscreen displays are identified by Android as a Mouse. The two are very much different in operations and device definition. ([Android Input Device Configuration Files](http://source.android.com/tech/input/input-device-configuration-files.html)). This could be the reason for scrolls and clicks are not working. I'm yet to find a touchscreen monitor with proper drivers for Android. :(

I've found the Dev Guide to the touch input devices [here](http://source.android.com/tech/input/touch-devices.html). Seems there are a lot of differences with a mouse and a touchscreen. I think your problem could be overcome by using the proper drivers for the touchscreen.

[This forum discussion may be of some help to you](http://www.mp3car.com/newbie/150868-android-drivers-for-usb-touchscreens.html)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a few companies trying to manufacture Android tochscreen monitors:

Hanns.G is working on a monitor which provides wireless touchscreen support for android:
http://liliputing.com/2011/09/two-way-sync-between-an-android-tablet-and-a-touchscreen-monitor.html
http://hackaday.com/2011/07/11/running-android-on-large-touch-screen-displays/