# What is a correct usbHidReportDescriptor for Android?

Tags: android, usb, touch, hid

I am implementing a USB touchscreen interface, which needs to work on Android.

From https://github.com/denilsonsa/atmega8-magnetometer-usb-mouse/blob/master/firmware/main.c#L159 I first tried:

```
// Mouse
0x05, 0x01,              // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
0x09, 0x02,              // USAGE (Mouse)
0xa1, 0x01,              // COLLECTION (Application)
0x85, 0x02,              //   REPORT_ID (2)
0x09, 0x01,              //   USAGE (Pointer)
0xa1, 0x00,              //   COLLECTION (Physical)
// X, Y movement
0x09, 0x30,              //     USAGE (X)
0x09, 0x31,              //     USAGE (Y)
0x26, 0xff, 0x7f,        //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (32767)
0x75, 0x10,              //     REPORT_SIZE (16)
0x95, 0x02,              //     REPORT_COUNT (2)
0x81, 0x42,              //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs,Null)
0xc0,                    //   END_COLLECTION
// Buttons
0x05, 0x09,              //   USAGE_PAGE (Button)
0x19, 0x01,              //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1)
0x29, 0x03,              //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 3)
0x25, 0x01,              //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
0x75, 0x01,              //   REPORT_SIZE (1)
0x95, 0x03,              //   REPORT_COUNT (3)
0x81, 0x02,              //   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
// Padding for the buttons
0x95, 0x05,              //   REPORT_COUNT (5)
0x81, 0x03,              //   INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
0xc0                     // END_COLLECTION
```

This worked correctly on Ubuntu 16.04, but did nothing on Android 6.

Then, from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1001891/A-USB-HID-Keyboard-Mouse-Touchscreen-emulator-with "First alternate Touchscreen Descriptor" I tried:

```
0x05, 0x0d,                    // USAGE_PAGE (Digitizer)
0x09, 0x02,                    // USAGE (Pen)
0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)

// declare a finger collection
0x09, 0x20,                    //   Usage (Stylus)
0xA1, 0x00,                    //   Collection (Physical)
// Declare a finger touch (finger up/down)
0x09, 0x42,                    //     Usage (Tip Switch)
0x09, 0x32,                    //     USAGE (In Range)
0x15, 0x00,                    //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
0x25, 0x01,                    //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
0x75, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (1)
0x95, 0x02,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (2)
0x81, 0x02,                    //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)

// Declare the remaining 6 bits of the first data byte as constant -> the driver will ignore them
0x75, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (1)
0x95, 0x06,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (6)
0x81, 0x01,                    //     INPUT (Cnst,Ary,Abs)

// Define absolute X and Y coordinates of 16 bit each (percent values multiplied with 100)
// http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/Hut1_12v2.pdf
// Chapter 16.2 says: "In the Stylus collection a Pointer physical collection will contain the axes reported by the stylus."
0x05, 0x01,                    //     Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
0x09, 0x01,                    //     Usage (Pointer)
0xA1, 0x00,                    //     Collection (Physical)
0x09, 0x30,                    //        Usage (X)
0x09, 0x31,                    //        Usage (Y)
0x16, 0x00, 0x00,              //        Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0x10, 0x27,              //        Logical Maximum (10000)
0x36, 0x00, 0x00,              //        Physical Minimum (0)
0x46, 0x10, 0x27,              //        Physical Maximum (10000)
0x66, 0x00, 0x00,              //        UNIT (None)
0x75, 0x10,                    //        Report Size (16),
0x95, 0x02,                    //        Report Count (2),
0x81, 0x02,                    //        Input (Data,Var,Abs)
0xc0,                          //     END_COLLECTION

0xc0,                          //   END_COLLECTION
0xc0                           // END_COLLECTION

// With this declaration a data packet must be sent as:
// byte 1   -> "touch" state          (bit 0 = pen up/down, bit 1 = In Range)
// byte 2,3 -> absolute X coordinate  (0...10000)
// byte 4,5 -> absolute Y coordinate  (0...10000)
```

Which worked on Android, with the slight niggle of a mouse pointer appearing whenever the screen was touched.

What is a correct usbHidReportDescriptor for Android?

Update:

The current behaviour is seen when sending "3" for buttons, i.e. "Pen Down" and "In Range".

If I send "2":"In Range" I get just a non-clicking mouse pointer.

If I send "1":"Pen Down" I get a non-absolute circular cursor.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what is your question. You see a mouse pointer where you would expect not to see it? Is that your question? Well that is Android behaviour. If the descriptor moves the pointer and does a click, the descriptor is working correctly. There is nothing wrong with the descriptor. Why does Android do that? You should ask Android developers. I have never tested on Android, but I recommend you to use a real hardware device that behaves as you would expect it and then study the descriptor of that device and clone it.

Comment: The idea of a "Pen" device is that you move the pen over a drawing surface and you can see on your screen where the pen is even if the pen does not touch the drawing suface. If you use a finger instead of a pen, you may already get a completely different behviour. Did you also test my other descriptors?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11896471

Comment: @Elmue Thanks for publishing your descriptors, they have been very useful.  The problem with "study the descriptor of that device" is that working devices are glued into phones and tablets, so I can't easily study them with Wireshark on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

A cursor appears as you are emulating a stylus, not a touch pad.

This line:

`0x09, 0x02,                    // USAGE (Pen)`

Should be:

`0x09, 0x04,                    // USAGE (Touchscreen)`

From my experimentation I think the 3 states of a styles are hovering high above the surface (0), not cursor is shown, hovering close to the surface (1), a cursor is shown, and clicking / touching (2).

For a full touchscreen HID descriptor example see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/touchscreen-sample-report-descriptors?source=recommendations#sample-report-descriptor